# Check for return of callback in express.js

Tags: express

I am trying to call a service for a post method:

```
router.post('/execute', myservice.execute);
```

Inside myservice.execute:

```
execute(req, res) {
    ...
    res.send(someinfo);
}
```

But this is a service, and I don't want it to bother about the req and res.  I would like to do something like below:

```
router.post('/execute', myservice.execute, (req, res) => {
    // if myservice.execute returns someinfo, i will call res.send(someinfo); otherwise will send new Error()
});
```

Is it possible to check for the return of a callback?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `myservice.execute` be a business what returns `someinfo` instead of calls `res.send(someinfo)`. Then, in route file:

```
router.post('/execute', (req, res) => {
    var someinfo = myservice.execute(req);
    // check `someinfo`, i will call res.send(someinfo); otherwise will send new Error()
});
```

Or you can use `middleware` pattern:

```
execute(req, res, next) {
    ...
    req.someinfo = someinfo;
    next();
}
```

In router side:

```
router.post('/execute', myservice.execute, (req, res) => {
    var someinfo = req.someinfo;
    // check `someinfo`, i will call res.send(someinfo); otherwise will send new Error()
});
```

Comment: Actually, my intention is not to have req, res parameter in my execute method.  But in your answer, I still need to pass in the req or res in the method.  Is there a different way?

Comment: `var someinfo = myservice.execute(req, res);`

Comment: i actually don't want to have this method `execute(req, res) {}`... i just want `execute() {}`

Comment: Inside myservice.execute:

execute(req, res) {
    ...
    res.send(someinfo);
}